# В чем разница между ядром процеССОРа и процеССОМ?

Tags: процесс, процессор, ядро

Не путайте процессы с процессорами, это совсем разные вещи! Я просто заметил что многие не правильно читают и думают что я говорю про многопроцессорность вместо многопроцессности, или наоборот.

Процессы можно услышать из питона и когда ядра операционных систем изучаешь (В [Википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) можно много раз услышать это понятие).

Как я понял что в одном ядре может быть несколько потоков, а также я слышал что одном процессе может быть несколько потоков.

Да что это за ваши процессы!?

Comment: Процессор, это камень, а процесс, это юнит который на нем исполняется

Comment: Ядро процессора - это часть процессора (или физически, или логически, т.е. может быть как бы виртуальная часть процессора), это исполнитель кода. Процесс - программа, код, то что исполняется ядром процессора. Можно сравнить ядро с человеком-рабочим, а процесс - с работой, которую этот рабочий выполняет.

Comment: `Процесс` - это буквально процесс вычислений. Пока программа работает она "в процессе вычислений". А `процессор` это обычно устройство, которое выполняет программы записанные в машинном коде. Про разницу между ними смешно говорить. Они очень далеки друг от друга. Одно - абстрактное понятие, второе - железяка.

Answer (score 0):

> Как я понял что в одном ядре может быть несколько потоков, а также я
> слышал что одном процессе может быть несколько потоков. Да что это за
> ваши процессы!?

Всё правильно - у процессора CPU свои потоки доставки инструкций к исполнительному ядру, а у ОС свои программные потоки. Физически это разные вещи, хотя и работают в тесной связке. Ядро CPU делится на **"FrontEnd"** (конвейер), и **"BackEnd"** (неспосредственно исполнительная часть).

• Конвейер включает в себя: кэш L1, блок предсказания переходов, декодер инструкций, секвенсер (вычисляет адреса), блок переименования регистров, и планировщик. Поскольку архитектурно вся эта часть находится вне исполнительного ядра, её назвали "FrontEnd". Основное назначение конвейера - разложить инструкции на микро-операции "mops", обеспечив тем-самым ядро работой.

• Само исполнительное ядро "BackEnd", или "Execution Unit", включает в себя уже несколько блоков ALU (аналого-логическое вычислительное устройство), FPU (floating-point unit, устройство обработки инструкций с плавающей точкой), а так-же SSE/AVX (блоки обработки мультимедиа + векторных инструкций). Планировщик передаёт мопсы в эти блоки через соответствующие порты ядра, которых в зависимости от м/архитектуры может быть от 0 до 8 штук. Так это выглядит в IntelCore:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь представлено ядро с одним потоком исполнения, где поток определяет как-раз конвейер. Но как выяснилось при тестах, ядро в такой схеме большую часть времени бездействует, например когда происходит кэш-промах, или результат одной инструкции зависит от другой, и т.д. Более того, практика показывает, что программисты редко используют инструкции FPU/SSE/AVX, в результате чего их блоки в ядре фактически простаивают, а вся нагрузка ложится на целочисленные ALU.

Чтобы загрузить ядро хотя-бы на 80%, инженеры Intel добавили в "FrontEnd" ещё один конвейер, а архитектурное решение представили миру как **"HyperThreading"** HT. Другими словами, теперь имеем один "BackEnd" с двумя конвейерами, при этом для операционной системы такой "союз" видится как 2 физ.ядра, хотя на самом деле второе ядро считается логическим.

Например как и ALU, блок FPU способен исполнять и целочисленные операции типа `fiadd/fisub/fimul/fidiv`, а значит когда ALU загружен, можно вторым потоком отправить часть инструкций и в FPU, что несомненно добавит профита. В технологии НТ второй конвейер имеет свой кэш L1, и свои регистры, что делает его полноценной производительной единицей.

В свою очередь ОС тоже предоставляет программистам возможность создавать потоки, но уже программные - не нужно путать их с аппаратными потоками ядра CPU. Однако связь между ними всё-же просматривается. В Windows софт-потоки создаются API-функцией `CreateThread()`, и это тоже независимая единица со-своим стеком и регистрами. Треды "Thread" являются частью процессов, и даже если мы не создаём софт-потоки, процесс всегда имеет базовый Thread(0).

ОС имеет свой планировщик, который выделяет одинаковые кванты времени каждому из многочисленных софт-потоков в системе. В десктоптных ОС 1-квант равен 12 мкс, по истечении которых планировщик сохраняет весь "контекст регистров" текущего потока в сегменте состояния задач TSS (Task State Segment), после чего передаёт управление следующему потоку в очереди, на такой-же квант времени.

Планировщик ОС ведёт учёт всех ядер CPU, которым передаёт софт-потоки на исполнение - это позволяет сохранять баланс нагрузки на все ядра. Когда софт-поток попадает в конвейер(N) ядра CPU, весь свой квант он будет исполняться строго на данном конвейере(N). Но благодаря тому, что при переключении потока планировщик сохраняет значение всех его регистров в сегменте TSS, следующий свой квант этот-же поток может отработать в конвейере уже соседнего ядра, и т.д. Таким образом, софт-потоки и потоки CPU (в лице конвейеров) тесно связаны между собой, о чём собственно и свидетельствует термин "тред" в `HyperThreading` и `CreateThread()`.